# theta divisor on a principally polarized abelian variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose we have a principally polarized abelian variety X over the complex number field.
Given two ample, effective divisors D_1, D_2 such that the global sections of both line bundles are 1 dimensional vector spaces.
If D_1 and D_2 have the same first Chern class, then is it true that D_1 and D_2 differ by a translation, i.e., there is x in X such that D_1 + x = D_2 as divisors? Why or why not?

Comment: Is that a homework problem? Why not read Mumford's "Abelian varieties" or, really, any book on abelian varieties?

Comment: Please provide definitions, etc., for everything.  Writing them out both helps you think about the definitions, and also lets those of us who do other areas of math have better access to the question.  I've  seen the definition of "effective divisor" before, but don't remember it off the top of my head, and "ppav" is just an acronym to me.

Comment: @Theo: I'm always a bit ambivalent about comments such as yours. I can see your point on one level, but on another level, if you don't what a ppav is then probably you're not going to be answering this question. I could take any question about functional analysis at MO and 'complain' that some of the terms are unknown to me, but even if they were explained to me I wouldn't be able to answer the question.

Comment: Writing things out have other benefits: helping people who don't know that much but interested to learn more easily, making it easier to find the relevant questions when  you search. Plus more carefully written questions are more likely to get answers and also sort of morally  force the responders to put in more efforts as well, etc. 

Comment: I'm going to agree with both Kevin and Hailong.  For the asker to write all that out won't really make it more likely that say, Theo (who doesn't know ppav's) will answer, but it makes the asker think things through a bit, and it also establishes the common notation, as to which definitions are the ones that the asker thinks we should use.

Comment: Questions on MO are not just written for the people who might answer, they're also written for people searching on the internet.  Defining an "effective divisor" isn't necessary in my opinion, though I would encourage it; its definition is easily found on Wikipedia.

On the other hand, it's rude to use an acronym if you can't find out what it means by Googling.  There's no math results (other than this question) for PPAV in the first 3 pages of Google hits.  I've gone ahead and edited the question to expand the acronym.

Comment: Typing "ppav math" into Google pulls up lots of hits.

Comment: Hailong and Ben's comments mostly get at why I leave comments on especially terse questions asking for more content.  But there's another reason.  One of the most valuable, in my mind, services a place like MO provides is as an environment for folks to talk math publicly.  It's not unlike Gowers' Polymath experiments in that regard.  I'm unlikely to have anything mathematically useful to say in response to Wayne's question, but I do appreciate being able to _understand_ the question --- watching other people ask and answer questions is a great way to learn foreign areas of mathematics.

Comment: -1: The question had a positive score, so I had to do my best to correct it. As Alexeev and Conrad already pointed, the answer is in chapter 1 of any text on Abelian varieties.

Comment: @DL -- I'll bite: please exhibit a text on abelian varieties in which this result occurs in Chapter 1.  

Comment: Hey Pete, the principle behind the comments of DL and AV is valid: this is a "homework"-level question for any course on abelian varieties, readily deduced from what is in any decent introductory book, even if not literally in Chapter 1. It doesn't seem a bad idea to discourage the posting of MO questions which are easily answered by what is found in introductory textbooks on a topic. Those books were written for a reason, after all. It's like the old story about teaching someone to fish... 

Comment: Dear Brian, To me it is not really meaty enough for a homework question -- it is more like a check on the definitions.  I also think that for every student who is taking a course on abelian varieties, there must be several more who are trying to learn this material on their own.  It is currently a matter of debate -- within the MO community, and even within myself -- to what extent we should answer "straightforward" questions.  This question in particular has had so many comments that I felt it deserved an actual answer...

Comment: ...Let me ask you this: suppose a graduate student you knew who was reading about abelian varieties came to your office and asked you this question.  Your answer wouldn't be "Look in any text on abelian varieties", would it?  Rather, you would call attention to the specific fact that is used -- the surjectivity of the map $\varphi_L: \operatorname{Pic}(A) \rightarrow \operatorname{Pic}^0(A)$ and give them some idea of where this could be found in the text they are reading.  (And you wouldn't claim that it's in Chapter 1, because that's simply false, and therefore quite unhelpful.)  

Comment: @Brian- You're right; I should have caught that one.  I still stand by the principle that using acronyms is something would should be done with great care, and that it goes in a slightly different category than just the question of whether to define terms.  

Comment: @Pete:  I think discussing things in person (as with your hypothetical student coming to my office) has a huge amount more value than most things on MO.  

I agree with Ben that it is better to write out what ppav means in the question. 

Answer (score 6):

This is true.  For $A_{/\mathbb{C}}$ an abelian variety, $L$ an ample line bundle on $A$, then any line bundle 
$M \in \operatorname{Pic}^0(A)$ -- over $\mathbb{C}$, this is equivalent to having first Chern class zero -- is of the form $T_x^{*} L \otimes L^{-1}$ for some $x \in A$.  (e.g. Theorem 1 on p. 77 of Mumford's *Abelian Varieties*).

Applying this theorem with $L = L(D_2)$, $M = L(D_1) - L(D_2)$, we get that

$L_1 - L_2 = T_x^*(L_2) - L_2$, so

$L_1 = T_x^*(L_2)$.

So $D_1$ and $x+D_2$ (meaning translation of $D_2$ by $x$!) must be linearly equivalent, but by your assumption $h^0(L(D_1)) = h^0(L(D_2)) = 1$, they are each the unique effective 
divisors in their linear equivalence classes, so we must have $D_1 = x + D_2$.